# Error while reading JSON file with Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am getting an error while reading JSON file using python's `json` module and I'm not able to understand what is wrong. Below are my files and code for your reference:

```
json.load(files_lst[1])
```

error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

After reading several answers I also tried:

```
json.loads(files_lst[1])
```

but I get the following error:

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

What is wrong here? Thanks a lot for your help

```
>>> files_lst
['All_Transcripts/x3021_10.50.48.111_04-04-2019.json',
 'All_Transcripts/x5363_09.33.36.955_08-27-2019.mp3.json',
 'All_Transcripts/x3580_11.35.53.462_05-13-2019.json',
 'All_Transcripts/x4342_08.55.01.523_08-01-2019.json',
 'All_Transcripts/x9496_15.26.32.382_05-21-2019.json',
 'All_Transcripts/x5374_08.38.15.692_06-17-2019.json',
 'All_Transcripts/x4342_13.43.57.128_03-21-2019.json']
```

Answer (score 0):

`json.load` accepts an open file descriptor. So you should call it like this:

```
json.load(open(files_lst[1]))
```

`json.loads` accepts a json as a string. So you should call it like this:

```
json.loads(open(files_lst[1]).read())
```

Comment: Hi Nadav, Thank you for your answer but I'm still getting the same error `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)`

Comment: I can't tell from here what your issue is because I don't if you used `json.load` or `json.loads`, and what the contents of the files are. If you attach your updated code and the contents of the faulting line I might be able to tell if it's a bug, or if the format of the json is invalid.